# Leiningen installation failed on ubuntu 14.02

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to install leiningen on ubuntu following the steps on leiningen [website](http://leiningen.org/#install) . first I tried to install it behind the proxy it didn't work then I used the network without the proxy and it's still giving me the same error.

```
usman@usman-pc:/bin$ lein run
Downloading Leiningen to /home/usman/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.5.1-standalone.zip now...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
Failed to download    
https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.5.1/leiningen-2.5.1-standalone.zip (exit code 77)
It's possible your HTTP client's certificate store does not have the
correct certificate authority needed. This is often caused by an
out-of-date version of libssl. It's also possible that you're behind a
firewall and haven't set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.
```

I even change the .jar extension to .zip in the lein script it's still not working. anyone good with clojure who can help?

Comment: i'd guess, that the error message there holds all the truth.  if you expect this only to be a problem with curl and your m2 setup is working fine (or else just more of the same problems are ahead), then download that file in the error message by other means and move it to `~/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.5.1-standalone.jar`

Comment: The problem you are having doesn't seem to be related to **Clojure**. Try using `curl` the same way it's being used inside the `lein` script so that you can troubleshoot your connection issue.

Comment: for linux its a zip file and i did download the file and placed it in the given path the problem is when i create a new project for the first time it needs to download some files from github and gives the same error again

Comment: okay finally it started working with permissions set as root. thank you anyway for the help.

Comment: `lein` doesn't require root to run. Something must be wrong.

Comment: then why is it working just fine with root and gives error otherwise? any solution? @Davyzhu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs
```

Then:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

It has to do with `curl` looking for the certificates in that location.